# After Delete Macro not working on all tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

My job recently upgraded to office 2016, and I created some After Delete Macros in Access 2016 to save deleted data from some tables in graveyard tables.

These work fine for the tables where I had to create the graveyard tables after going to Access 2016, but the tables that already had graveyard tables won't work. I used graveyard tables on the old access (2007) by adding a delete column, checking delete for rows that will be deleted, then running a query that moved all the ones marked delete to the graveyard table.

I feel this has to be connected to the issue behind it. I have a split DB, and have imported the new tables, updated the tables with the link manager, etc. I am really dumbfounded as to why it only works for some tables, and those are the tables that got a newly created graveyard table.

Comment: Please include the relevant code and table structure

Comment: I found the problem. One of the fields is long text, and it will fail if that field is included, but will work without it.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with data macro's, but it likely is. At least in MS SQL, you can't use those types of fields in triggers.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your help.